# Adding a delimiter in front of a regex match in python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have the following text chunk here and would like to add a delimiter in front of the clause number (4.1 ... 4.2 ..., etcetera)

```
4.1 Use unique passwords (Manual)
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eu velit a libero convallis hendrerit. Nulla interdum fermentum viverra. Maecenas tincidunt sollicitudin odio. Aenean a erat sagittis, lacinia nulla eu, ornare velit. Suspendisse tempor at nisi eu mattis. Phasellus in ante magna. Quisque nisl lacus, fermentum pulvinar odio id, auctor sagittis nisl. Proin bibendum cursus orci vitae finibus.

4.2 Set password lifetime (Automated)
Quisque ut vehicula diam. Maecenas ac nulla cursus, dictum odio ac, lobortis dui. Nullam euismod, enim sed mollis elementum, tellus urna porttitor augue, ac venenatis tortor diam eget leo. In euismod dapibus tortor et vehicula. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque id rutrum libero. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nullam sollicitudin pellentesque magna sit amet malesuada. Aenean pulvinar metus sed justo tincidunt, et fermentum sem gravida. Aliquam varius lacus sit amet aliquam elementum. Pellentesque a varius magna, at euismod ligula. Praesent odio nunc, faucibus vel urna non, varius porta velit.
```

Such that the 'delimiter' would be present for every clause in the text:

```
'delimiter' 4.3 Set password expiry warning (Automated)
Quisque ut vehicula diam. Maecenas ac nulla cursus, dictum odio ac, lobortis dui. Nullam euismod, enim sed mollis elementum, tellus urna porttitor augue, ac venenatis tortor diam eget leo. In euismod dapibus tortor et vehicula. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque id rutrum libero. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
```

I am using re.sub to perform matching and replacement but I am not too sure how to do without removing the clause number entirely:

```
result = re.sub(r'[0-9\.]{3,}\s*[A-Z][\d\w\s/\-\,\(\)\\\"]{1,}\s*\(Automated|Manual\)', 'delimiter', text)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)? .*\((?:Manual|Automated)\)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `.*\((?:Manual|Automated)\)` Match a space and either `(Manual)` or `(Automated)` in the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jbwUAA/1)

In the replacement, use the delimiter followed by the full match

```
delimiter \g<0>
```

For example

```
import re

regex = r"^\d+(?:\.\d+)? .*\((?:Manual|Automated)\)"

s = ("4.1 Use unique passwords (Manual)\n"
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eu velit a libero convallis hendrerit. Nulla interdum fermentum viverra. Maecenas tincidunt sollicitudin odio. Aenean a erat sagittis, lacinia nulla eu, ornare velit. Suspendisse tempor at nisi eu mattis. Phasellus in ante magna. Quisque nisl lacus, fermentum pulvinar odio id, auctor sagittis nisl. Proin bibendum cursus orci vitae finibus.")

result = re.sub(regex, r"delimiter \g<0>", s, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Output

> delimiter 4.1 Use unique passwords (Manual) Lorem ipsum dolor sit
> amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eu velit a libero
> convallis hendrerit. Nulla interdum fermentum viverra. Maecenas
> tincidunt sollicitudin odio. Aenean a erat sagittis, lacinia nulla eu,
> ornare velit. Suspendisse tempor at nisi eu mattis. Phasellus in ante
> magna. Quisque nisl lacus, fermentum pulvinar odio id, auctor sagittis
> nisl. Proin bibendum cursus orci vitae finibus.